# I'm trying to get emails from server using imaplib in Python, but it didn't print anything

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to get and print all emails from server using imaplib in Python, but it didn't print anything. I have gone through [I want to grab all emails from an inbox using the Python IMAPLIB module... how can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892218/i-want-to-grab-all-emails-from-an-inbox-using-the-python-imaplib-module-how-c) and [the imaplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example). But the code didn't print the mails.

```
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)


## login
mail.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

status, messages = mail.select('INBOX')
print(status)

if status != "OK":
    exit("Incorrect mail box")
print(messages)

typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

Here, the print(status) prints 'OK' but print(messages) prints [b'0']. Several answers from stackoverflow i have analyzed. I'm stuck in this, any suggestions. I want to print all the emails in the particular mailid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python IMAPLIB HTML body parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522113/python-imaplib-html-body-parsing)

Comment: That seems to indicate there are zero messages in the inbox.